# Finding related model in laravel based on parent

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I want to search for like which is made by a given user on a given post.
I have one **Post** model as: Post

```
class Post extends \Eloquent
{


    protected $fillable = [];

    public function likes()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('Like', 'likeable');
    }


}
```

and one **Like** model as:

```
class Like extends \Eloquent
{
    protected $fillable = [];

    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphTo
     */
    public function likeable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }

    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
     */
    public function owner()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User', 'owner_id');
    }

}
```

and default **User** model provided in laravel.

now I have queried **Post** model to find one post using post_id like

```
$post=Post::find(10);
```

and **User** model like

```
$user=User::find(1);
```

now I want to find Like made by this **User(1)** on **Post(10)** Is there any function available in laravel for this.

I know that I can directly query Like using raw where function as

```
\Like::whereLikeableId('10')->whereLikeableType('Post')->whereUserId('1')->get();
```

but this looks ugly and I want to know laravel way of doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is:

```
$like = $post->likes()->where('user_id', 1)->first();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that worked. Is there any way of doing it like: Like::likeable($post)->where('user_id', 1), I mean the other way round so that this becomes independent of parent Model

Comment: You can use `whereHas` but I don't think it would make things easier. Why would you want that?